# why can't i change my regional settings?

Tags: windows, settings, regional

for about 2 hours i've been trying to find solutions on how to change my advanced regional settings(the one for language used in non-unicode programs) ..because everytime i try to change the language ...the system gives me an error that says:
Setup was unable to install the chosen locale. Please contact your system Administrator.

So what do i have to do?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you may need to be an admin to do that. Have you tried that?